# grails : deployement error on tomcat ( resources not found )

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tomcat, grails

I have a grails application.
I make a war with 'grails war' then I deploy it on Tomcat.
I have the following errors :

ERROR resources.ResourceMeta: Resource not found: /js/application.js

ERROR resources.ResourceMeta: Resource not found: /js/bootstrap.min.js

ERROR resources.ResourceMeta: Resource not found: /css/bootstrap.min.css

I unzip my war file and I have the following :

**fjLearning.war** :

css/

```
main__v1385391634036.css
main__v1385391634036.gz.css
..
```

js/

```
jquery-1.8.3.min__v1385391634036.js
...
```

...

I tried to access to the full path of the resource :
**mysite.com/fjLearning/static/js/application__v1385389616024.js**
, and it's OK.

But, if I try to access to **mysite.com/fjLearning/static/js/application.js**, it doesn't work.

To check that the problem comes from files names, I change manually all of them.
Then, I deploy again my war file and it works !

So do you know where does theses files names come from ?

PS :
I suspect ui-performance plugin so I will check if I use it correctly ...

**My configuration :**

- This project is on GitHub : https://github.com/drieu/fjLearning
- Grails : 2.3.3
- Tomcat : apache-tomcat-7.0.47

Comment : I can run this application with grail run-app without problem.

**Buildconfig.groovy :**

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.4"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    //build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
}
```

Config.groovy :

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
    }

    bootstrap {
        resource url:'js/bootstrap.min.js'
        resource url:'css/bootstrap.min.css'
        resource url:'css/main.css'
        dependsOn 'jquery'
    }
}
```

Comment: First, try to put the full path to review if you can load the file (then, if you can review your files, modify your relative path to match the full path with the developer console)

Comment: If you look in the uncompressed application, in the Tomcat, those files exist?

Comment: Thanks for you answers.It permits me to go further ! I have completed my question.

Comment: Problem solved.
I think the problem comes from a bad installation of ui-performance plugin.
I clean all directories in .grails/ and I remove all references of ui-performance in the application (BuildConfig.groovy and in application.properties).
So now it works.I can deploy my war in Tomcat.

Thanks for your answers.It permits me to find the answer.